# module not found error in Jupyter but works at command prompt

Tags: pip, miniconda

I have installed nb-black package using pip. It is working at the command prompt but not in Jupyter.

```
# python3
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 23 2020, 22:25:07)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nb_black
>>>

# which python3
/root/miniforge3/bin/python3

# which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter

# python
Python 3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 23 2020, 22:25:07)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import black
>>> import nb_black
>>>
```

But in Jupyter notebook I do always get "Module not found" error.

---

I just noted that this is happening with almost all new modules. For e.g. seaborn can be imported from command prompt but not from Jupyter.

Comment: Your python3 is at `/root/miniforge3/bin/python3`, but your jupyter is at `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`. This implies jupyter is not in the conda environment. Maybe you need to install jupyter in conda.

Answer (score 0):

This is because I was downloading older version from...

```
wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/4.8.3-4/Miniforge3-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

Once I downloaded the latest one, it solved the problem.

```
wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/23.1.0-3/Miniforge3-23.1.0-3-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

I was downloading older version because I copy-pasted from a script written a few years back.